# Python: numpy loadtxt with integer and datetime

Tags: python, numpy, types

I don't understand how works the loadtxt methode of numpy. I have read some questions/answers on the website but it's not clear for me.

I have a file 'data.txt' which is :

```
WEIGHT,DAY
75.1,16/10/2018
75.2,17/10/2018
...
```

My code is :

```
def parsetime(v):
    print(type(v))
    print(v)
    return np.datetime64(
        datetime.strptime(v, '%d/%m/%Y')
    )

data = np.loadtxt('masse.txt',delimiter=',',usecols=(0, 1),converters = {1:parsetime},skiprows=1)
```

But it doesn't work correctly cause it's giving to the function parsetime a byte and not a string...

```
<class 'bytes'> 
b'16/10/2018'
```

I just want an np.array which has in first column an integer and the second column a date.

I'am a bit lost.
Thanks a lot by advance,

Comment: np.genfromtxt() or you can use pandas then convert the data to array

Comment: I get the same problem with genfromtxt(), it gives a byte and not a str. Plus I can't skip the first row.

Comment: u tried this right .. np.genfromtxt('test.txt', dtype=str, delimiter=',')

Comment: Thanks for your comment. No I haven't add dtype, but adding this doesn't solve the problem.
data = np.genfromtxt('masse.txt',dtype=str,delimiter=',',usecols=(0, 1),converters = {1:parsetime})

<class 'bytes'>
b'16/10/2018'
<class 'bytes'>
b'16/10/2018'